# MS Access Upserting Records based on Data from other records in same table

Tags: ms-access, upsert

I want to automatically add and update records to calculate totals for light bulbs. This is for a Sales Order for goods that will be sold to the customer. The sales associate will enter a part number of a light fixture, information for the installer, and the quantity of items needed. All other information will be pulled from another table, I've left pricing etc out because it isn't relevant.

I want the order form to automatically add another line item for the number of bulbs that need to be on the order as well.

Example data, entered by associate:

```
ID   | PartNumber | Info | Qty | BulbQty | BulbInfo
1    | 563        | Hall |  3  |    2    |   A19
```

As that gets added to the table, I want to automatically add a new record, with a blank part number, [Info] = [BulbInfo], [Qty] = [BulbQty] * [Qty].

Example data, plus automatic line item calculating light bulbs to be delivered:

```
ID   | PartNumber | Info | Qty | BulbQty | BulbInfo
1    | 563        | Hall |  3  |    2    |   A19
2    |            | A19  |  6  |         |
```

Now if a new line item gets added with A19 bulbs, I want to add to my bulb record's Qty (based on Info = BulbType) instead of adding a brand new record. Of course if a record gets changed or deleted, now I need to deduct that from the relevant bulb record. I have lots of different bulb types, so I need this to be dynamic based on the value of [BulbQty] for new incoming records.

Comment: Why would you want to store a sum in a table instead of just using a query?

Comment: To expand on @ChristopherD. comments - you shouldn't store an "on hand" quantity, you should always calculate it. More reading on the subject here http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: This sales order is going to be used to update the inventory table quantities, as well as create a purchase order. The light bulbs are their own seperate line item because they are an inventory item as well that gets bought and sold.

Comment: I would say that your data model isn't correct based on your description, and the example above. You wouldn't store the calculation from the first line as a new record in your second line. That makes no sense from a database perspective whatsoever. You would simply have a transaction line qty that is calculated from your order once it is accepted  - Qty -6  Part No 563 . You don't store Inventory quantities - you store transactions and calculate stock levels. Did you read the link?

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding. What I'm doing here is a sales order form, where a sales associate enters in the quantity of fixtures that a customer is ordering. I want the sales order form to automatically add another line item for the number of light bulbs that the customer needs to also recieve with their order.

Comment: Possible options: 1. code sets the DefaultValue property of controls for the Info and Qty fields, user enters PartNumber on new record line and fields populate, 2. code runs INSERT sql to add record directly to table then refreshes the form, 3. code uses form's recordsetclone to add new record, 4. code moves to new record row and enters values to controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a private sub that gets called every time a quantity gets updated, passing [BulbType] and my sales order number so that I only alter the current sales order.

First if [BulbType] is "", exit the sub. Then I used DCount to find existing instances of [BulbType] in [Info]. If there were multiple instances (in my case there shouldn't ever be, but just in case), prompt to delete them all. Next if there are zero instances, add one where [Info] = [BulbType]. Then if there was only one instance (by now there should be), create a recordset of all instances of [BulbType]. Now just run through that recordset and keep adding to a totalQty variable to get my total. Add that total to the [Qty] field in my sales order using a DLookup, since I know that there's only one instance where [Info] = [BulbType].